# How to use Expression in the LINQ SubQuestion

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQToSQL  question and I need to apply the same "where" in 2 places.

```cs
var batchCollection = _db.Packets.Where(PacketsFiltering(model));
```

My function

```cs
private static Expression<Func<Packet, bool>> 
    PacketsFiltering(StorageDataRequestViewModel model) {
    return p => p.DepartmentId == model.DepartmentId &&
    p.CreationDate <= model.Date &&
    !p.IsPendingSeparation &&
    !p.IsDeleted &&
    (p.Set.Shipping.StatusCode == "NOT_LOADED" ||
    p.Set.Shipping.StatusCode == null ||
    p.Set.Shipping.LoadedDateTime >= model.Date);
}
```

And I need to use this Expression in Subquery

```cs
var batchCollection = _db.Pitches
    .Where(x => x.Packets.Where(PacketsFiltering(model))).Count() > 0)
```

But the primary query has a get parameter  Expression, the second query has a Func.

I tried to do this code and anyway I got the exception

```cs
var batchCollection = _db.Pitches
    .Where(x => x.Packets.AsQueryable().Where(PacketsFiltering(model)).Count() > 0)
```

And this

```cs
private static Func<Packet, bool> 
    PacketsFilteringCompile(StorageDataRequestViewModel model) {
    return PacketsFiltering(model).Compile()
}
```

In both ways, I got runtime exception

If somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try compiling the expression outside the lambda.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay How do you expect the query provider to translate that already compiled expression into SQL then?